# How to put ImageView on top of CardView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a layout like this, but I don't know how to place the CardView background under the ImageView and then set TextView below the image. The image should have 300dp height and 200dp width.

[image]

Comment: because that picture isn't part of the card view, it just stretches over it.

Comment: use another card to place the imageview and set higher elevation for this.

Comment: I know it is not a part of cardview. How I can set constraints for cardview with textView and another cardview for image. It should overlap same as the above example. Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constrain the bottom and top of your first card with the top of the second CardView, this allows you to align the center of the first card view with the top of the second CardView.
and so that the First CradView is above just add an elevation higher than that of the card below

for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="9dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".7">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="10dp"

        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_700"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomCard"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottomCard">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is the output

[image]

Comment: the one who asked the question told me that's what I'm looking for!. but whoever voted me down, please explain to me why? or propose an improvement

Answer (score 1):

you must use `app:cardElevation` attr for card view and use `android:elevation` attr for other views for do that